# Dell Latitude E7389 Headphones not working

Tags: sound, dell, alsa, headphones

When I plug in my headphones, the sound doesn't come out from them. They aren't detected in alsamixer.

```
sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 139
    Memory at ef228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ef200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3253 Analog [ALC3253 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Can someone help here on how can I make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Check in PulseAudio, under the Output Devices tab. Built-In Audio Analog Stereo. Right there you could switch between the built-in speakers or the headphones.

Comment: The only thing that is shown is Speakers I don't have any other option.

Comment: Codec: Realtek ALC3253

Answer (score 2):

**Install and run *hdajackretask*:**

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
sudo hdajackretask
```

**Forcibly connect the headphone jack pins:**

1. Under *Select a codec* choose *Realtek ALC3253*
2. Check the *Show unconnected pins* option
3. Under *Pin configuration* iterate each pin:

   - Click the *Override* box
   - Click the drop-down list and choose *Dock Headphone* if it exists
   - If *Dock Headphone* is not in the list then uncheck  *Override*
   - On the Dell E7389 you should override pins 0x16, 0x17 and 0x21.
   - Note the scrollbar to show the bottom of the list may be hard to notice.
4. Click on *Install boot override*
5. Reboot and it should work now

Comment: I just tried this on my Dell Precision 5510 running Ubuntu 18.10.  To my surprise, it worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on a Latitude 7389 with Ubntu 19.10.  Thanks so much!